# Sequence of holomorphic functions uniformly bounded on compact subsets uniformly converges to $0$ on compact subsets

Tags: complex-analysis, uniform-convergence, analytic-functions

> Let $\Omega$ be an open connected subset of $\Bbb{C}$ and let $f_n$ be a sequence of holomorphic functions on $\Omega$ that is uniformly bounded on each compact subset of $\Omega$. Suppose there exists a point $a \in \Omega$ where $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n^{(k)}(a)=0$ for each $k=0,1,2,...$. Show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n = 0$ uniformly on each compact subset of $\Omega$.

Honestly, I've thought about this problem intermittently for quite a while now and haven't had much success in coming up with any decent ideas. I could use some help.

Answer (score 0):

It suffices to show that every subsequence $\{f_{j_n}\}$ of $\{f_{n}\}$ contains a sub-subsequence locally uniformly convergent to 0.

Since $\{f_{j_n}\}$ is locally uniformly bounded, then there exists a locally uniformly convergent sub-subsequence $f_{j_n'}\to f$ (Montel's Theorem.)

Clearly, $f\equiv 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

Step 1:

Let $\Omega$ be an open connected subset of $\Bbb{C}$ and let $f_n$ be a sequence of holomorphic functions on $\Omega$ such that $f_n\to f $ locally uniformly on $\Omega$ then $f\in H(\Omega) $ and moreover $f_n^{(k)}\to f^{(k)}$ locally uniformly on $\Omega$. (Very interesting!)

Step 2 :

$f\in H(\Omega) $, $\Omega \subset \Bbb{C}$ open and connected. If $\exists a\in \Omega$ such that $f^{(k) }(a) =0$ for all $k=0, 1,2...$, (a zero of $f$ of infinite order) then $f=0$ on $\Omega$. (again very interesting!)

Now your task is to finish the proof.